# ¿Como separar las filas de un textarea en variables diferentes? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

quiero contar los datos separados por una coma ( , ) de una fila de un textarea para poder verificar si algún dato esta vacío, si esta vacío el botón de guardar se desactiva .

-Cada fila tiene máximo 3 datos separados por coma.

Tengo una función que cuando le envió una sola fila en el textarea esta validando los espacios en blanco , pero cuando le envió dos o mas falla la validación. 
Ejemplo:

Cuando  envio una fila me verifica correctamente y activa el boton.

**familia 1, grupo 1, descripcion 1**

Cuando envío dos  y la segunda incompleta me toma todos los datos como una sola fila y me activa el botón (en este caso el botón debería estar desactivado).

**familia 1, grupo 1, descripcion 1**

**familia 2, grupo 2**

```js
$("#copea").on("keyup", function() {

  obtener()

})

function obtener() {
  var variable = $("#copea").val();
  salto = variable.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < salto.length; i++) {
    var row = salto[i];
    var primero = row.split(",")[0];
    var segundo = row.split(",")[1];
    var tercero = row.split(",")[2];
    if (primero != null) {
      var p = primero.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
    }
    if (segundo != null) {
      var s = segundo.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
    }
    if (tercero != null) {
      var t = tercero.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
    }
    if (p == null || s == null || t == null || p == "" || s == "" || t == "") {
      $("#IngCopear").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#IngCopear").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea name="copea[]" id="copea" cols="79" style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%" rows="10" placeholder="familia 1, grupo 1, descripcion 1
familia 2, grupo 2, descripcion 2
..."></textarea>
   <button type="submit" id="IngCopear" name="IngCopear" class="btn btn-success copear pull-right">Guardar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que inicializar las variables con null.  Ademas, yo chequearia por `undefined` en lugar de `null`.  Algo asi:

```js
$("#copea").on("keyup", function() {

  obtener()

})

function obtener() {
  var variable = $("#copea").val();
  salto = variable.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < salto.length; i++) {
    var row = salto[i];
    var primero = row.split(",")[0];
    var segundo = row.split(",")[1];
    var tercero = row.split(",")[2];
    var p = null;
    var s = null;
    var t = null;
    
    if (primero != undefined) {
      p = primero.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
    }
    if (segundo != undefined) {
      s = segundo.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
    }
    if (tercero != undefined) {
      t = tercero.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
    }
    if (p == null || s == null || t == null || p == "" || s == "" || t == "") {
      $("#IngCopear").attr("disabled", true);
      break;
    } else {
      $("#IngCopear").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea name="copea[]" id="copea" cols="79" style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%" rows="10" placeholder="familia 1, grupo 1, descripcion 1
familia 2, grupo 2, descripcion 2
..."></textarea>
   <button type="submit" id="IngCopear" name="IngCopear" class="btn btn-success copear pull-right">Guardar</button>
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm, solo un detalle, agregar la instrucción break dentro del if, debajo de $("#IngCopear").attr("disabled", true);. Esto porque si fuera la primera linea del textarea la que estuviera incompleta y la segunda completa, el bucle for en la segunda iteracion activaría el botón, cuando no debería ser así. Por eso agregar un break, para que en cuanto consiga una fila irregular desactivar el botón y suspender las iteraciones